# is it possible to return a function from another function in C?

Tags: c

I have a project in C. In the **function adminpanel()**  there are some selections such as add, delete, modify etc. Each of these selections is a function.Now, for example i call the **add() function** and when it ends i need to return at the begging on the **adminpanel() function** to make another selection. This happens with the **delete()** etc.
Is it possible to set as return value in the function **add(), delete()** etc. the function **adminpanel()** ? If not, what i have to set as a return value?

Comment: No. You can't return a function or arrays from a function. It's possible to return a pointer to a function.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder; No. Not a dupe of that.

Comment: @haccks: The standard for "is this a dupe" is "Does an answer to the other question answer this question." So yes, it's a dupe. (If I were making the rules, the rule would probably be different.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: So if you do not like the rules, why stick to them? ;-)

Comment: @alk: Because otherwise, chaos.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to return a function pointer:

```
int inc( int x ) { return x + 1; }
int dec( int x ) { return x - 1; }

int( * func( int t ) ) ( int )
{
    return t ? &inc : &dec;
}

int test_C( void )
{
    int( *f1 )( int ) = func( 1 ); // f1 = &inc
    int x1 = ( *f1 )( 1 );         // x1 = 2            

    int( *f2 )( int ) = func( 0 ); // f2 = &dec
    int x2 = ( *f2 )( 1 );         // x2 = 0    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `return inc;` would do, as well as `... = f(1);` would.